# iPhone Notes app is not loading all my notes but I can search for them from Home screen

Tags: iphone, notes.app

I am using the Notes app on iPhone 7 plus running  iOS 10.2.1. I don't use iCloud.

However, a few days ago, the Notes app stopped loading all my notes. My notes app shows nothing.

However, when I search for a note using Spotlight Search, I can see the search result. When I tap on it, it opens the Notes app and showing an endless loading animation on the top of screen. Again, it doesn't load the notes.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem and recover my notes either by transferring them to a Mac/PC or just fix the Notes app to load all my notes?

Comment: It could be that you need to update or that the battery may need to be replaced to maximize performance.

Comment: Thanks for reply is there any way to copy all the notes from terminal to MacBook or pc without updating?

Comment: I think you can share via iCloud or AirDrop. But again, the notes don’t load. You may want to update and see how it goes. It is always a good idea to keep your device up-to-date.

Comment: @JBallin I never used icloud to backup notes before this problem! Should i add iCloud account?

Comment: Why aren’t you using icloud? In that case, I would plug the phone into ur Mac and create a backup (and try to confirm the notes are indeed backed up). And then I would try connecting to icloud to see if that does anything. If not, I would restore from the backup. Possibly you can get to the raw notes within the backup itself? Just spitballing, hope that helps.

Comment: I agree that keeping your phone up to date is a good idea too - trying to update is another option (as mentioned). I’m not sure if one of these options will accidentally remove your notes, which is why I cant give one clear solution.

Comment: You tried restarting your phone, right?

Comment: @JBallin Thanks for trying to help. Yeah i force restart as well . I am looking for a step by step tutorial that it tells me how to backup iphone then extract notes from it(to mac or pc) . I am sure notes are not deleted as i can search for them from home screen!Only problem is how to recover them !

Comment: Possibly you can update this question to ask how to extract notes from an iPhone backup. To backup you just plug into your Mac and you should see the iPhone in finder. Those steps should be easy to find on google.

Comment: @JBallin backing up to mac will not alter existing notes data on iphone?

Comment: AFAIK Backing up should be harmless and not alter the data on the phone. But maybe that’s another thing to include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are looking in the right folder. When you open Notes, you should see the word Folders near the top of the window to the left. Tap on Folders and it will list all the Folders in Notes. Select the folder you want and the Notes app should display all the notes in that folder.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Folders show only on my phone and notes folder ( see the pic i posted)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching your phone to aeroplane mode and then loading the notes?

I recently ran into an issue where i couldn't view the actual note but i could see them in the main list

Comment: This can't be a potential solution because the OP owner says s/he does not use iCloud.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/326350)